# What do the cosets of the group $E/Z(E)$ look like? (E is the quantum error group and Z(E) is the centre of E)

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code, pauli-group

If I have the quantum error group $E$ which contains elements of the form:

{$ \pm w_{1} \otimes \dots \otimes w_{n}, \pm i w_{1} \otimes \dots \otimes w_{n} $}

The centre of $E$:

$Z(E) = <iI> = ${ $\pm I, \pm iI $ }

The quotient group:

$E/Z(E) =$ {$eZ(E): e \in E $}

I am finding it difficult to see how the quotient group is an abelian group. However, I think this is because I can't visualist what cosets of the form $eE(Z)$ might look like? Would someone be able to give an example of one of these cosets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of the n-fold Pauli group are either commute or anti-commute. In the quotient over the center they will all commute, since $-1$ wouldn't matter. Note that a general element of the Pauli group has the form
$$
i^k w_{1} \otimes \dots \otimes w_{n},
$$
where $k=0,1,2,3$ and $w_j$ are Pauli matrices. Four elements for each $k$ together form a coset, and as a coset representative you can just take $w_{1} \otimes \dots \otimes w_{n}$.

Same reasoning works for subgroups of the Pauli group.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I understand most of it now, except for this part:

" In the quotient over the center they will all commute, since $−1$
 wouldn't matter. "

Can you explain why $-1$ doesn't matter here?

Comment: $-1$ is in the center $\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$ which we factor out. More precisely, it's coset representatives which commute up to factors in the center.